# Listview раскрывающиеся элементы

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, style

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать вот такие дочерние объекты у listview? Точнее как называется тип этих дочерних объектов, а дальше я уже сам разберусь :)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Expander.​​​​​​

Comment: Спасибо @Discord, вы напишите это как ответ и я отмечу вопрос как решённый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из описания неясно, что у вас за задача, поэтому посмотрите две вещи:

- Класс [**Expander**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) — элемент управления, реализующий подобное разворачивание. Состоит из нажимаемого заголовка и разворачиваемого содержимого.
- Свойство [**CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.groupdescriptions.aspx) и всё с ним связанное, при помощи которого реализуется "родная" группировка в списках. В конечном счёте по умолчанию она работает через тот же Expander.